# batch file to run two application and when 1st app closed, other will be close too

Tags: windows, batch, autohotkey

Its a game called SubwaySurfer for pc, to run it through your keyboard we need to set autohotkey, what I need is when user click to play a game the autohotkey file will be run too, and when the game exit the autohotkey closes too.

I created a .bat file with code

```
@ECHO off 
Start SubSurf.ahk 
start Subway_Surfers.exe
```

i need SubSurf.ahk automatically shutdown when Subway_Surfers.exe closed as by user.

any trick ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
echo next line should continue to exe
Start "" SubSurf.ahk

echo next line should wait in batch
Subway_Surfers.exe

:: next line kills SubSurf
TSKILL SubSurf /V
```

please replace `SubSurf` with right process name in the `TSKILL SubSurf /V` command; ; could be `SubSurf.ahk` for instance...

Verified with

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@echo :: start "" calc
start "" calc
@echo :: calc running
@echo :: notepad running, "%~nx0" batch waits
notepad
@echo :: notepad end %Errorlevel%
TSKILL calc /V
```

Output:

```
C:\bat>tolls
:: start "" calc
:: calc running
:: notepad running, "tolls.bat" batch waits
:: notepad end 0
End process (2620)

C:\bat>
```

Comment: when i close the Subway_sur the subwaysurf.ahk process is still running, you may test it here : https://mega.co.nz/#!jQlDGKiS!bzL2_JomG7AjA_UEsoUGndwuthPEYdArVxJglJu5xIs